# How to simplify this:$\sqrt{5\sqrt{3}+6\sqrt{2}}$?

Tags: nested-radicals

How to simplyfy this:$\sqrt{5\sqrt{3}+6\sqrt{2}}$.

I know I should use nested radicals formula but which one is $A$ and $B$.Using the fact $A>B^2$ you can find $A$ and $B$.

But $C^2=A-B^2$ isn't a rational number then we have again a nested radical.

What to do?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be from $\mathbb{R}$???

Comment: If $B>A$ then it will be a negative under radical.

Comment: Both terms look positive to me.

Comment: Sorry $A$ should be bigger than $B^2$

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: It should be sum of two radicals that arn't nested radicals.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Noticing that $5=3+2$, we spot a perfect square

$$\sqrt{\sqrt3(3+2\sqrt3\sqrt2+2)}.$$

---

Hence,

$$\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt[4]{12}.$$

Comment: Doesn't $\sqrt{\sqrt3}$ count as a nested radical?

Comment: @lhf: not as $\sqrt[4]3$ :)

Comment: "Noticing that $5=3+2$," brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{5\sqrt{3}+6\sqrt{2}}
&= \sqrt{5\sqrt{3}+\left(2\sqrt{6}\right)\sqrt{3}} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{6} + 3} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{4+4\sqrt{6}+\left(\sqrt{6}\right)^2}{2}} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\left(2+\sqrt{6}\right)^2}{2}} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\frac{2\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&= \sqrt[4]{3}\cdot\left(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}\right).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\root{5\root{3} + 6\root{2}}} =
\bracks{\pars{5\root{3} + 6\root{2}}^{2}}^{1/4} =
\color{#f00}{\pars{147 + 60\root{6}}^{1/4}}
\end{align}